# Align widgets without Stack in Flutter

Tags: flutter

**I know how to align Widgets with Stack properly** but I'm done using Stack because sometimes it gives me lots of headache when things become too messy. I would like to ask for that is there a way to **stack widgets without using Stack?** It is like Transform.translate can do the same thing but is there a more reliable way to do that?

```
            Container(
          height: 70.0,
          width: 70.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: bgDarkColorGradient,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                offset: Offset(0, 12),
                blurRadius: 24.0,
                spreadRadius: 0.0,
                color: Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 130),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.person_outline_outlined,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 35,
                right: 0,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 32.0,
                    width: 32.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      border: Border.all(
                        width: 4.0,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 77, 93, 144),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Icon(Icons.edit, size: 12.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

With this code, I almost achieved this output.[image: The widget]

**Lastly, my question is that is there a way to get these kind of results without using Stack?**

Comment: Maybe the better question is, why does it give you headaches?

Comment: @Syph sometimes I have to use different stacks together and it is hard to keep track of which one belongs the right parent. So I want to minimize the usage of Stack in my apps.

Comment: Feel like you shouldn't shy away from the Stack widget because of this but yea not sure what other options are good unless using CustomMultiChildLayout.

Comment: I agree with @Syph. One option for you to keep good track of your stacked widgets is create them in different files. For example, if you have need to stack 2 containers and 2 columns and after that stack these four widgets, you can create a separated widget with a stack for these 2 containers, another for the 2 columns stacked and then stack them in the screen you want.